# Show session information in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

How can you output the current session to the view?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833240/in-rails-from-byebug-how-can-i-view-the-output-of-the-session-variable-as-a-str/55834018#55834018 .   vasfed's answer of `session.to_h` shows some relevant aspects of session , the id and variables of it

Comment: Doesn't work as of Rails 5.1, `undefined method 'to_h' for #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x00007fdfb3f68778>`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`<%= session.inspect %>`

Comment: inspect works almost anywhere to get more info than you to_s is giving you. I use it all the time

Comment: `session.to_h` is pretty good too  as mentioned by vasfed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833240/in-rails-from-byebug-how-can-i-view-the-output-of-the-session-variable-as-a-str/55834018#55834018

Answer (score 7):

To those reading, I found another answer that also seems to work: `<%= debug session %>`.

Comment: Both of the solutions posted work, although this one has the added benefit of enclosing the output within a `<code class="debug_dump">` element. Don't forget however, that it's extremely important to add a conditional like so: `<%= debug(session) if Rails.env.development? %>`